# Can I send messages from a server to specific clients using jest-websocket-mock?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am testing a websocket that, upon a client connecting to the server, the server will send a message to that specific client with a simple hello message to demonstrate a good connection.

I am wanting to use [**jest-websocket-mock**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-websocket-mock) for this, however I cannot see a way of sending a message from the server to one specific client. I can only see the generic `server.send(message)` command to send a message to all clients connected to the server.

My code so far, which does send messages when a client connects:

```
const server = new WS('some_url');

const messages = { client1: [], client2: [] };

const client1 = new WebSocket('ws://some_url');
await server.connected;
client1.onopen = () => { server.send('welcome...') };
client1.onmessage = msg => { messages.client1.push(msg.data); };
```

When this connects, I do get the messages object outputted with:

```
{
    client1: ['welcome...'],
    client2: []
}
```

However when I add a second client:

```
const client12 = new WebSocket('ws://some_url');
await server.connected;
client2.onopen = () => { server.send('welcome...') };
client2.onmessage = msg => { messages.client2.push(msg.data); };
```

the `server.send(...)` will act globally and mean my outputted object is:

```
{
    client1: ['welcome...', 'welcome...'],
    client2: ['welcome...', 'welcome...']
}
```

is there a simple way I can get what I want, with only one of the `welcome...` outputs per client when added?

Comment: Have you tried `client1.send('welcome...')` or `client2.send('welcome...')`?

Comment: @Molda - That surley would be the clients sending a message to the server? I'm wanting the server to send a message to each individual client after it has connected to the server. Imagine you are connecting to a websocket to receive a stream of data, and upon connecting the first message you receive is "hello and welcome to our service...". Something like that.

Comment: No i meant server sending to the connected client `client2.onopen = () => { client2.send('welcome...') };` That's how it usually works but i'm not familiar with the library you are using though.